# Can two random variables have linear relationship but still be uncorrelated?

Tags: random-variables, correlation

If two random variables does not have linear relationship then they are uncorrelated even if they might be dependent. I am unable to come up with an example where two random variables have linear relationship but are uncorrelated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In particular, what does "have a linear relationship" mean, precisely?

Comment: @kimchilover one of the random variable is a linear function of the other. I found this post and thought that it is a usual terminology https://libanswers.lib.miamioh.edu/stats-faq/faq/343636